# Lambda expression with statement body error in previously working code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need help with this, I have a very important piece of code that I got help with from this thread

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509319/how-to-use-linq-to-group-sum-or-retrieve-total-my-current-code-returns-nothing)

The code is as follows:

```
var pln = db.tabStockPlanners
            .Where(y => y.ExpectedHarvestDate < addoneyear)
            .Where(r => r.Published == 1)
            .Where(f => f.Available == 1);

var gruppedList = pln.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID, (key, enumerable) =>
        {
            return new tabStockPlanner { ItemID = key, ExpectedYieldInTonnes = enumerable.Sum(k => k.ExpectedYieldInTonnes) };
        }).OrderByDescending(t => t.ExpectedYieldInTonnes).ToList();
```

But I get an error

> A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

I do not know if this is something that has changed with EF. Can someone help me with this? EF is version 6. Any issues with the current code?

**UPDATE**

What has worked perfectly is:

```
 var gplist = from x in db.tabStockPlanners
                     where x.Published == 1
                     where x.Available == 1
                     where x.ExpectedHarvestDate < addoneyear
                     group x.ExpectedYieldInTonnes by new { x.ItemID }
                     into g
                     select new { g.Key.ItemID, ExpectedYieldInTonnes = g.Sum() };
```

But I would like to also have the correct answer as per this syntax. Maybe someone can repost with the LINQ syntax. Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Hello Friends; @YosefBinmal solution worked well, along with @NetMage proposal for `AsEnumerable()` I am posting Yosef's solution with modifications to make it anonymous and return just the 2 columns needed. I removed the `tabStockPlanner` so its `new {` and it is solid. So marking that as correct. Any objections? It works well.

Here's the modified code

```
  var pln = db.tabStockPlanners
          .Where(y => y.ExpectedHarvestDate < addoneyear)
          .Where(r => r.Published == 1)
          .Where(f => f.Available == 1);

        var gruppedList = pln
            .AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(i => i.ItemID)
.Select(g => new { ItemID = g.Key, ExpectedYieldInTonnes = g.Sum(i => i.ExpectedYieldInTonnes) })
.OrderByDescending(t => t.ExpectedYieldInTonnes)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179341/a-lambda-expression-with-a-statement-body-cannot-be-converted-to-an-expression

Comment: I suppose you did update the framework?

Comment: Try replacing the tuple (key, enumerable) with new { key, enumerable }. It didn't work for me with tuples in EF6

Comment: This has *never* been supported in EF6 and earlier. You must have changed something. The difference with the other question is that the answer concludes the first query by `ToList()`.

Comment: @Gleb yes, I did update to EF6, previously this worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Amend:** The GroupBy extension method you are using takes an expression lambda as it's second parameter. Your lambda contains a `{ return ... }` statement that can't be translated into an Expression tree. Please see [CS0834](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0834).

You could avoid this error by writing:

```
var gruppedList = pln
    .GroupBy(i => i.ItemID) 
    .Select(g => new tabStockPlanner { ItemID = g.key, ExpectedYieldInTonnes = g.Sum(i => i.ExpectedYieldInTonnes) })
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.ExpectedYieldInTonnes)
    .ToList();
```

I like to use the overload of GroupBy that only takes keySelector (without the element selector). This way the LINQ pipeline becomes more readable in my opinion as each function has a single task.

Hope it helps you

Comment: This isn't really correct - the error means an `Expression` tree can't be created from the lambda, and that has nothing to do with SQL conversion.

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately this didnt work... Error: The entity or complex type 'maxmallModel2.tabStockPlanner' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: That's a different issue. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) can help you?

Comment: @NetMage You're right, got mixed up there! Amended the answer

Comment: You may want to repeat your comment to @noetico tagging the user so they will be notified you commented to them. It is a very good comment.

Comment: ok thanks for this! After putting `AsEnumerable()` before the `GroupBy` as NetMage proposed; it worked, one only problem being that it returned all the table fields, unlike the one I posted in the original thread that just returns `ItemID` and `ExpectedYieldInTonnes` which is good for graphs and a small grid display. I believe a small tweak @YosefBernal then we have a perfect option and if we all agree, a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
var gruppedList = pln.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID, (key, enumerable) => new tabStockPlanner { ItemID = key, ExpectedYieldInTonnes = enumerable.Sum(k => k.ExpectedYieldInTonnes) })
.OrderByDescending(t => t.ExpectedYieldInTonnes).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This code still returned this: The entity or complex type 'maxmallModel2.tabStockPlanner' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @noetico If you put `AsEnumerable` before the `GroupBy`, that will pull all the data at that point and do the `GroupBy`, etc. on the client side, and should work.

Comment: Ok so @NetMage ... Pln.AsEnumerable.GroupBy... ok I will give it a run.